# Is there currently a problem with LIKE box_count style?

Tags: html, facebook-like

I've used the box_count style for some time, the last few days it isn't working correctly, the button itself displays, but the count itself doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. its a global problem whilst facebook is doing some maintenence on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has applied hidden effect on box count because there is some maintenance work is going on.

It will be up in a day or two.